# How can I solve the error _Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>?' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter, dio, jsonserializer

I want to fetch by id and I get this error.
In the MarsatmasResponseModel, when you bring the data with an id of List type, Marsatmas is returned.I get this error.
`Parse Error: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>?' in type cast - response body: {data: {id: 1,  code: adc, date: 2023-04-29T00:00:00}}`
My getById method is like this.

```
 Future<MarsatMas?> getbyId({required int id}) async {
   MarsatMas? _market;
   String query = "${NetworkRoutes.MARSATMASGETBYID.rawValue}?id=$id";

   final response =
       await manager.send<MarsatmasResponseModel, MarsatmasResponseModel>(
     query,
     parseModel: MarsatmasResponseModel(),
     method: RequestType.GET,
   );
   if (response != null) {
     if (response.data != null && response.data!.data != null) {
       _market =
           response.data!.data!.first;
       return _market;
     } else {
       return null;
     }
   } else {
     return null;
   }
 }
```

This is my MarsatmasResponseModel;

```
class MarsatmasResponseModel extends INetworkModel<MarsatmasResponseModel> {
  final List<MarsatMas>? data;
  final bool? success;
  final String? message;

  MarsatmasResponseModel({this.data, this.success, this.message});

  @override
  MarsatmasResponseModel fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _$MarsatmasResponseModelFromJson(json);
  }
 @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson() {
    return _$MarsatmasResponseModelToJson(this);
  }
  factory MarsatmasResponseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
        return _$MarsatmasResponseModelFromJson(json);
  }
}
```

ChatGbt suggested me to do it this way=>   `parseModel: (Map<String, dynamic>? json) =>  MarsatmasResponseModel.fromJson(json??{}),`
When I do it like ChatGbt I get this error
`The argument type MarsatmasResponseModel Function(Map<String, dynamic>?) cant be assigned to the parameter type MarsatmasResponseModel.`

Comment: Can you share the response that you are getting from api ?

Comment: this response =>{
  "data": {
    id: 1,  code: adc, date: 2023-05-29T00:00:00
  
  },
  "success": true,
  "message": "Succes get id data"
}

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse object as list

For your provided response the parsed data class will be like this.

```
class ResponseData {
  InnerData? data;
  bool? success;
  String? message;

  ResponseData({this.data, this.success, this.message});

  ResponseData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    data = json['data'] != null ? InnerData.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
    success = json['success'];
    message = json['message'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.toJson();
    }
    data['success'] = this.success;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and

```
class InnerData {
  String? id;
  String? code;
  String? date;

  InnerData({this.id, this.code, this.date});

  InnerData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    code = json['code'];
    date = json['date'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['code'] = this.code;
    data['date'] = this.date;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and  For parse

```
ResponseData parseData = ResponseData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```